# why do we use far keyword in c?

Tags: c, pointers

I don't understand the reason using far pointer in the below code. Also my compiler does not  compile it. here's the code,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char far *p,*q;
    printf("%d %d",sizeof(p),sizeof(q));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Maybe legacy code of [8051](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/c51/c51_le_farmem.htm) micro...

Comment: For legacy reason... the legacy can be traced back to the good old days when memory are still addressed with 8-bit or 16-bit address and are segmented. From the dupe: "It's an old extension from the era of segmented memory architectures. It basically means "this is a pointer that needs to be able to point at any address, not just things in the same segment as the code using it"."

Comment: @Ian Not just legacy. There's still plenty of 8 and 16 bit microcontrollers getting used in new designs. Every such microcontroller with more than 64kb addressable memory will have some obscure way to access the extra memory. (This alone is reason enough to pick a 32 bit MCU when you need that much memory.)

Comment: @Lundin ah yes, even until today if you consider the 8-bit/16-bit uC... oh, I missed those days!

Comment: Side note: use `%zu` instead of `%d` to print sizeof values.